# Passport.js return access token without using sessions.

Tags: angularjs, session, express, google-oauth, passport.js

I am using the Google login strategies for passportjs. (I have tried using both [google-oauth2](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2) and [google-plus-login](https://github.com/sqrrrl/passport-google-plus)).

I am trying to build a restful stateless API using bearer access tokens for authenticated calls. So therefore, I do not want to use passportjs sessions.

Here is the flow of my web application (using Angular):

- User logs in via Google login.
- My API checks the Google user's email is located in the database of users able to login to the application.
- My API generates an access token for this Google logged-in user and returns the access token back to the Angular app.
- Angular app saves access token locally and uses token for future bearer auth requests.

My problem is that I am not sure passportjs was built for this. I cannot find a way *not* to use sessions.

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: config.getGoogleLoginCallback()
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, callback) {
  callback(null, profile);
}));

function googleLoginCallback() {
  // using req.user (The Google profile) to check my 
  // database if user's email exists in the database. 
  // If it does, generate an access token, save it to 
  // my database for the user, then return it back:
  res.send(new User(access_token)); // use User to send back json
}
```

I have sessions off with passport: `passport.authenticate('google', {failureRedirect: config.getGoogleLoginFailureRedirect, session: false})`.

It seems that everything would work great because well, it is working well. However, the line `res.send(access_token);` is the one line not working. In my web application, the access token is not sent back. My thought is that `res.send(access_token)` is sending back to Google as Google called my callback function?

How do I send an access token back in JSON format to the user to keep my API stateless?

Comment: Google is not calling your callback, it will redirect the user browser to the callback URL. You should give more actual code, your `googleLoginCallback` does not reveal anything you're actually doing.

Comment: @vesse, what code do you need to see? I didn't see a need to include that code. The comments give an idea of what the code is doing. Really, `res.send(new User(access_token))` I expect to return JSON back to the user's browser but this is not the case.

Comment: Oh, one guess - maybe `access_token` is a string? If I in the previous example would use `new Object('anystring')` the response body would be `"anystring"` which is not valid JSON and probably not parsed by Angular then.